# Newbie trying to create an instance

Tags: java, instance

I've been learning java the past week and I decided to practice.
I want to create an instance to call a number from the main class

The class I want to have is named "Clients"
In the main claSS I ask for the user to type his ID int 
I want to call the ID from the main class to the Clients class but I was unsuccessful
Both in same .java file

Could you help me out?
 I searched online but the code i found was too much for my brain to handle and I'm here stuck begging for an example

```
int userID = userInput; //In main
                int getUserID = new Client(); //My instance attemt. Failed
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a `Client` to an `int`. You want something like: `Client client = new Client(); client.setUserID(userID);`

Comment: You could also create a constructor in the `Client` class that takes an `int` parameter. Then you can create and set in one step: `Client client = new Client(userID);`

Answer (score 0):

In the second line you're trying to assign newly created object of class `Client` to a primitive type variable `getUserID` which is failing.

```
int userID = userInput; //In main
int getUserID = new Client(); //My instance attemt. Failed
```

If you want to assign object of class Client you need to assign that object in either type Client or it's parent class.

As for example if class ClientParent is parent class of Client, i.e.

```
Client extends ClientParent{
 ....
}
```

**The following examples hold good :**

```
 ClientParent instance = new Client(); // This will work as ClientParent is the super class of Client.
 Object instance1 = new Client(); // Object is a super class of any class.
 Client instance2 = new Client();// You can assign in same type.
```

Hope the above examples will clarify your confusions.